# Passing Non Existing Directory As a parameter in IIS or Apache

Tags: apache, iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

First look at this url:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xoxoxo/

This directory does not exists but somehow stackoverflow can pass that last directory as a parameter to his base script.

Is this possible to configure IIS or Apache to do so? How?

Comment: When I follow that link I just get the page header, no content.

Comment: No you can see at the right: 

0 questions tagged

Comment: Also seeing that page means that this non existing directory are handling somehow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mechanism behind this kind of behaviour is called **url-rewriting** and can be implemented in **Apache** with the [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)-modules and in IIS with either Helicons [*ISAPI_Rewrite Lite*](http://www.helicontech.com/download-isapi_rewrite.htm) (or one of the non-free alternatives offered by Helicon) for **IIS 5.1** and **6** or with the [*Microsoft URL Rewrite Module* for **IIS 7**](http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1691).

For example the following settings will ensure that every request that cannot be matched on an existing file or directory will be transfered to the `index.php` file.

**`mod_rewrite`** (`.htaccess` in your document root directory or somewhere in your `httpd.conf`)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR] // IF is file (with size > 0)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR] // OR is symbolic link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d      // OR is directory  
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]               // DO NOTHING
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]       // TRANSFER TO index.php
```

***ISAPI_Rewrite Lite*** (in the appropriate dialog of your IIS settings)

```
// uses same syntax as mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

***Microsoft URL Rewrite Module*** (in your `web.config` in the document root directory or seomewhere in the configuration tree)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="MatchExistingFiles" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="RemapMVC" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```